# How do I make Dialogue?

Tags: lua

recently I've been trying to make some sort of dialogue system in Lua just to learn but It won't work?

```
local Dialogue
Dialogue = "Ah! It seems you have found me.. may I ask a question?"
local DialogueContinued = "What's your name..?"
local BoyWat = "That's fine..."
io.write(Dialogue)
local Options = "Yes","No"
if io.read("Yes") or io.read("yes") then
    io.write(DialogueContinued)
end
if io.read("No") or io.read("no") then
    io.write(BoyWat)
end
```

Comment: What do you think `local Options = "Yes","No"` does? What do you think `io.read("Yes")` does?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, doesn't work is not a proper problem description.

`local Options = "Yes","No"` will assign `"Yes"` to `Options` and discard `"No"`

You can either put both strings in a table

```
local Options = {"Yes", "No"}
```

or assign two variables

```
local Option1, Option2 = "Yes", "No"
```

See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.3

`io.read("Yes")` is equivalent to `io.input():read("Yes")`  You cannot use this like that. If you want to read from the console use `io.read()` without any aruments.

See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.read

If you want to check wether the user has entered Yes or No use

```
local entered = io.read()
if entered == "Yes" or entered == "No" then
-- your code
end
```